# Searchbar in tableView and reload data

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I can not search because my search bar is a header of tableView and then I reload tableView  I have not search results.

I know there is a lot of ways to solve it but what is more wisely?

My code

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)sectionIndex
{
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 270, kRowHeight)];
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 270, kRowHeight)];
self.searchBar.delegate = self;
view.opaque = NO;
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.searchBar.opaque = NO;
self.searchBar.translucent = NO;
self.searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[view addSubview: self.searchBar];
self.searchBar.barStyle = UISearchBarStyleDefault;
self.searchBar.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin ;
self.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];

return view;
```

}

And I want that then I scroll tableView my searchBar will disappear in top and then I scroll up it will appear. Is any simple to do it?

Comment: Why not using UITableViewController?

Comment: @Grzegorz Krukowski, what do you mean?

Comment: WHy don't you put the search bar outside the tableview?

Comment: yep, I will do it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use tableHeaderView and not section header. Just put in your viewDidLoad

```
UISearchBar* searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 270, kRowHeight)];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
```